# Getting domain information from NTLM message

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ntlm

I am using NTLM with Chrome/Windows/Active Directory/Node.js to login to a webpage. It works but I have a question about the response data in the NTLM message that doesn't seem to be covered in the RFC [or the only "rfc" type thing I can find](https://curl.se/rfc/ntlm.html).

Using `express-ntlm` this package properly extracts the Username, Workstation, and Domain, but I also see some extra info that would get me the full domain name, eg `foo.bar.com` which would be really useful for me.

This response message is of type 3 and it contains as mentioned above, but it seems to contain some extra information that doesn't seem to have parsing rules such as how to find the byte offset or length of data. I am wondering if it is not really part of the RFC and just some random data that I cannot rely on.

Here is what the NTLM message looks like when received on the server side to complete the authorization. I am replacing the actual data with some fake domain names. It's also really weird that each letter has a space between them.

> NTLMSSP ╚     �   �╔�╔�   X          `z       <╗  ║��� �D���╔═ ╝ ╗   0 0            0  ╗`\���85=�E+z]�Rwȗ��O�1���T6. d o m a i n
> . com ╚ F O O . bar . d o m a i n
> . c o m ║ 0 b a r . d o m a i n . c o m �
> �+�I8�+fy��q�      . H T T P / 1 0 . 1 1 1 . 2 2 . 3 3 3 : 3 0 0 0

Basically you have NTLMSSP and within all the weird characters you have the domain name, workstation, and username. Then there seems to be supplemental data about the full domain name and where the request came from. But again I don't see this specced out anywhere. Is it reliable? Is there a way to extract it?

Answer (score 0):

•   The NTLM SSP handshake message received by the server side is a null terminated ASCII string for a binary encoded UTF-8 message due to which it was not visible and displayed symbols on a Windows system. To decode and extract information from this NTLM SSP message, you can use the github script ‘NTLMRaw unhide’ for this purpose.

•   The NTLM SSP message received by you on the server side is a type 2 challenge sent from the client to server. To extract credible information from the NTLM SSP message, you have to capture information and network traffic through the ‘netsh.exe’ and ‘pktmon.exe’ tools and export them without conversion. These exported traffic monitoring files are captured as ‘.etl’ files on windows systems.

•   You will have to parse these network packet capture files in ‘NTLMRawUnhide.py’ python3 script and extract NTLMv2 hashes in a readable format. Below is the link of github repository to the NTLMRawUnhide.py script: -

https://github.com/mlgualtieri/NTLMRawUnHide

https://www.mike-gualtieri.com/posts/live-off-the-land-and-crack-the-ntlmssp-protocol

Also, below is the sample output image of the packet capture: -

[image: NTLMRawUnhide Output]